# Ajax php return include

Tags: php, ajax, include

I am using jQuery ajax and php to return some html content and echo it in my page. Content get returned successfully but it also includes number 1 at the end of response which I dont want. I guess its the same at this question:  [php include prints 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086695/php-include-prints-1/48742686)

Can I get rid of number 1 at the end because its visible in my page?

If I remove echo $content how do I return this to javascript where I use it?

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: awp_data.ajax_url,
        data: ajax_data,
        dataType: 'text',   
    }).done(function(result) {
    
        activePreset.html(result);

        
        
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }); 
}
```

php

```
public function get_preset_custom_settings() {

        $result = dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/preset_config/'.$_POST['preset'].'.php';
                
        $content = require($result);
        if ($content === false) {
            echo ('Failed to load preset settings!');
            exit;
        }

        echo $content;

        wp_die();
        
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of `echo $content;`.

Comment: But how do I return this to javascript where I use it if I remove echo?

Comment: The script you're calling with `require()` is already doing that. Everything it outputs will be returned to JavaScript.

Comment: You're already seeing that. The `1` is being added by `echo $content;`.

Comment: Than this is an answer to the question and should be clearly written. Now I understand.

Comment: It's the same problem as the linked question. `echo require(...)` is the same as `$variable = require(); echo $variable;`

Comment: In fact, that's true for any function.