# Concatenating strings in PHP using require() without printing 1 as part of the output

Tags: php

My question is related to [php include prints 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086695/php-include-prints-1). In https://github.com/jaimemontoya/jaimemontoya.com/blob/dev/page.php I'm using this:

```
public function Display()
{
   echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n\t<head>\n";
   $this -> DisplayTitle();
   $this -> DisplayFavicon();
   $this -> DisplayMetaKeywords();
   $this -> DisplayMetaDescription();
   $this -> DisplayMetaViewport();
   $this -> DisplayStyles();
   echo "\t</head>\n\t<body>\n";
   $this -> DisplayHeader();
   echo "\t\t<div class=\"container\">\n";
   echo $this->content;
   echo "\t\t</div>\n";
   $this -> DisplayFooter();
   echo "\t</body>\n</html>\n";
}
```

The problem happens in `echo $this->content;`. In https://github.com/jaimemontoya/jaimemontoya.com/blob/dev/index.php I'm using this:

```
<?php
  require("page.php");
  $index = new Page();
  $index->content .=
  require("scala-programming-projects/scala-programming-projects-book-info.php");
  require("success-habits-dummies-zeller/success-habits-dummies-zeller-book-info.php");
  .....
  .....
  .....
  $index->Display();
?>
```

The problem is the '1' that is printed because the `include()` method, after successfully including the desired file, returns a `TRUE` value that when echo'ed out is '1'.

[image]

Do you have specific suggestions to refactor my code to get rid of that '1' or maybe `php.ini` or some configuration can help in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php include prints 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086695/php-include-prints-1)

Comment: @Progman No, it doesn't because simply not using `echo` and only using `include()` without the `echo` is not working for me. I need the `echo` to print out the variable where have the string that has concatenated all values that come from different `require()` elements.

Comment: The problem is you have `$var .= require ...;`, you are adding the return value of `require`, which is usually the boolean value `true`. In a context of strings, this get translated to `"1"`, which gets added to the variable (in your case `$index->content`). This is what the linked question is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your `scala-programming-projects/scala-programming-projects-book-info.php` already concat the string. just remove concatenation on index.php

```php
<?php
  require("page.php");
  $index = new Page();
  
  require("scala-programming-projects/scala-programming-projects-book-info.php");
  require("success-habits-dummies-zeller/success-habits-dummies-zeller-book-info.php");
  .....
  .....
  .....
  $index->Display();
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean removing concatenation here?: https://github.com/jaimemontoya/jaimemontoya.com/blob/dev/scala-programming-projects/index.php.

Comment: No, at this file https://github.com/jaimemontoya/jaimemontoya.com/blob/dev/index.php, remove line no 4

Answer (score 0):

```
$index->content .=
  require("scala-programming-projects/scala-programming-projects-book-info.php");
  require("success-habits-dummies-zeller/success-habits-dummies-zeller-book-info.php");
```

Instead of doing this ,you should get the output of the require calls into a variable using output buffering.
as an example ,

```
ob_start();
require('bla.php');
require('blabla.php');
 $index->content .= ob_get_clean();
```

because require calls directly echoes the output at the place where you call them so there is no meaning in assigning it to a variable, which is your mistake here and require returns 1 which is getting printed as well