# Why does php include statement return whitespace as ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, whitespace, removing-whitespace

An example of my question in the title demonstrates the problem I'm having.

[example](http://wx2fly.com/test/cssPositioning.html)

sorry don't know how to use jsfiddle.

And how do I fix it?

Comment: show your code? not the output. May be you have putted that space accidentally.

Comment: Are you sure `emptyFile.php` is empty - no spaces or new lines or anything?

Comment: what do you want to see? Its one page, two buttons each to a php file called by $.ajax The php code is displayed there is nothing in the emptyFile.php

Comment: yes - emptyFile.php is EMPTY created in notepad++ with only a name.

Comment: how about emptyFile.php format ? ANSI,UTF8 BOM... try utf8 without bom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your "empty file" contain an empty line, http://wx2fly.com/test/emptyFile.php , which means it's not empty !

I think you can fix your problem by making your empty (or not) file starts with `<?php`, and be sure the php tag is NOT closed at the end of the file.

Comment: Put up your suggestion `file starts with <?php no closing` Result returns NOTHING. Also put up `open and closing tag` file with the same whitespace result.

Comment: Seems that when using Notepad++ File>New File>SaveAS saves a file size 3 bytes - NOT EMPTY as expected. Using just the `open tag <?php` then did the job. Quite confusing! Thanks

Comment: It's pretty hard to save an empty file with any editor (even vi ). On unix, you can "touch" an inexistant file to do the job, or type `:> myEmptyFile.php`. If not available (like windows), you may create a file containing only `<?php ?>` (and no space or newline after), or simply the opening php tag