# PHP - Placing html in variable on out of php tag

Tags: php, html

I have question, how to placing my html content like this:

```
<?php
$html = 
?>
//in this space, i will place my html
<span></span>
<?php
; 
?>
// and i print it
<?php echo $html;?>
```

Comment: You are looking for output buffering, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-ob-start-in-php

Comment: have you considered reading the documentation?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: hei who's vote down my answer ?
i know how to write variable clearly...
But i have long html lines and i so confused ...

Comment: You can't do it ? What are you trying to get done ?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use heredoc syntax? Can you not have the HTML inside a PHP variable? Or do you have a large amount of HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need output buffering for this.

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<!-- your html code here -->
<span></span>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: your answer is right very right !
like my answer ...
at first, but you are advance !
thanks ...

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do that between the PHP tags?

```
<?php
  $html = '<span></span>';
  echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: yes i know, but the span is a html contents that contain many html tag and every tag have string and i must convert it ...
Oh please help me !

Comment: Can you please give a more elaborate example of what you want to store in the variable? It would make it easier to assist you in this matter.

Comment: oh thanks, i has fix it...
and please see my answer at bottom !

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you might want to have a look at [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. However, your question is not exactly clear.

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOT
<span></span>
<!-- You can place anything in here "without escaping" -->
EOT;
echo $html;
?>
```