# php admin login think to do with getting the db row

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Currently doing a site that needs a admin panel and i have a php problem, on inserting the values of the username and password correctly, it doesnt seem to be getting the row count. Here is the php code:

admin_login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location:index.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); 
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); 
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); // query the person
    $existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the row nums
    if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
         }
         $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
         $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
         $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
         header("location: index.php");
         exit();
    } else {
        echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

the connect to the sql db works fine and i did a echo to make sure it works

Here is the index.php php code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["manager"])) {
    header("location: admin_login.php"); 
    exit();
}

?>
<?php 
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["id"]); 
$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["manager"]); 
$password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION["password"]); 
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
 if(!$existCount == 0){
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
?>
```

I do believe it is a error in the $existCount and its not getting the count?

Cheers

Comment: 1) You're wide open to SQL Injection attacks.  *At least* use `mysql_real_escape_string`.  2) You're storing passwords in plain text.  **Never do that.**  3) You're modifying the password before storing it, why exactly?  4) You're using `mysql_*` libraries which are woefully out of date.  *At least* switch to `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: Does $existCount return 0? Or something else?

Comment: returns as 0 Pete, David thanks will try fix what you have said, i am just doing the basics to make it work before i go back and secure it even more, will try get to grips with the mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably with the final if statement. Change:

```
if(!$existCount == 0){
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
```

to:

```
if($existCount == 0){
     echo "Your login session data is not on record in the database.";
     exit();
}
```

Note the missing `!`, which negates the expression in a way you don't want.

Comment: hello cheers for that :) however i dont get to that pointyet i cant get off the admin login i get the That 'information is incorrect, try again click here' echo

Comment: after `$sql = mysql_query(...` try putting: `if (!$sql) print(mysql_error());`, it will at least tell you if there is an error in your SQL.

Comment: just tryed it and nothing came up

Comment: ok, try `print()`ing `$manager`, `$managerID` and `$password` after your regex filters, and compare them directly with the database values, just to be sure that they do actually match.

Comment: the if (!$sql) print(mysql_error()); code, it didnt upload, just re-uploaded and came back with this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''admin' WHERE username='Guest' AND password='********!' LIMIT 1' at line 1
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/56/11391856/html/storeadmin/admin_login.php on line 21

Comment: its not getting the password i enterd in the password box, its getting the server password instead?

Comment: yeah i just relised cheers mate, would appear there is a error with getting the password, ill try changing the $password to $user_password!

Comment: ok, I hope you have it sorted, although from the sounds of it I wouldn't be surprised if your error persists. It appears that your SQL is wrong, and as it looks syntactically correct, I would assume it was either that: a) your table name is incorrect, b) your field name(s) are incorrect or c) badly escaped parameters are causing syntax errors

Comment: ok cheers mate yeah think i see the error now! Cheers mate you have helped one heck of a lot :D

Comment: yeah changed syntax a bit and im in and it works! Cheers for you help

Comment: brilliant :) could you include the solution in your question for others? and ofc feel free to accept/upvote this answer if you found it helpful ;)

Comment: I managed to get the admin as 'admin' in the $sql causing the error and also the $password was taking the $password from the connect_to_mysql.php file,

$manager = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["username"]); 
    $user_password = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST["password"]); 
    // Connect to the MySQL database  
    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$manager' AND password='$user_password' LIMIT 1");

Comment: wont let me upvote :( altho now have error on the header part : header("location: index.php"); it comes up with Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/56/11391856/html/storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php:1) in /home/content/56/11391856/html/storeadmin/admin_login.php on line 26

Comment: make sure nothing is being output/printed to the browser before the calling `header()`. this includes any whitespace (characters / new lines). and, you should be able to accept the answer if not upvote?

Comment: Fond a solution = changed the header to a echo to a url heres the snipit of code finnished -     if ($existCount == 1) { // evaluate the count
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
   }
   $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
   $_SESSION["manager"] = $manager;
   $_SESSION["password"] = $user_password;
   echo'<script> window.location="Desired URL"; </script> ';
         exit();
    } else {
  echo 'That information is incorrect, try again <a href="index.php">Click Here</a>';
  exit();

Comment: be careful that any files you `include()` don't call `header()` when the file which included it has already written to the browser

Comment: that sounds ok, but a bit of a work around ;) consider using output buffering if you can't find a better way to fix it (which you should :p) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-ob-start-in-php

Comment: will look into it :P been pulling my hair out over the login for past 3 days haha will look into it when i go into securing it a lot more :) cheers bud

Comment: haha yes, one thing at a time, I get it. but make a note of it for the future if nothing else - it's useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are taking the code from developphp. 
By using above code, if your password has some characters are not alphanum, can cause the filter remove them and unmatch to the database and return $existCount as zero.