# Check to see if PHP session exists not working

Tags: php, session

I am trying to find a way to check whether there is a session. And if there isn't, redirect back to the start.php page.

These are the pages I have made.

## start.php

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

## form.php

#### Above the `head`:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

#### In the `body`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
}
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

## Attempt

I have putting this above the head of the form (along with what is there now) but it just keeps me on the start.php page

```
<?php 
  if (!isset($_SESSION["name"]))
   {
      header("location: start.php");
   }
   else{
   }
?>
```

## more info

So currently if there is no session and I enter `form.php` it will redirect me to `start.php`. But if there is a session it will stay on `form.php`.

But if I start on `start.php` and submit the form (creating the session and moving to `form.php`) it will straight away redirect me back to `start.php` (the same page)?

## code of the two pages in full:

### start.php

```
<?php session_start(); ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


    <form action="deletethis.php" method="post">
        <p>Please enter your name to continue:</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

### form.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["name"]))
   {
      //header("location: delete1.php");
      die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.'delete1.php'.'" />');
   }
   else{
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
}
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
echo $name;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

## What I have decide to do instead

```
if (strlen($name) <1){
    echo '<script> window.location.replace("delete1.php");</script>';
    }
```

Comment: More Important !!! you need to write your session_start() on the top of your index page and put this code also ob_start(); at the beginning your page..

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU  `ob_start();` where? form.php or start.php?

Comment: @user2768038.. you need to put ob_start(),session_start() in each and every page or else you just create header.php and put your session_start() and ob_start() and include into your every pages.refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-ob-start-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

on each page in the very beginning..

So, the code should be like this

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION["name"]))
   {
      //header("location: delete1.php");
      die('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=\'delete1.php\'" />');
   }
   else{
   }
?>
```

Comment: Still not working :( Please look at my full code above

Comment: Yes haha. I have know idea why it didn't work for ages. So weird!