# PHP: How to store HTML as it is in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I know mySQL has no issue to store html tags as it is. I want to know how can I store just by escaping commas, and quotes and put HTML as it is in PHP?

To give further idea, I fetched a SQL backup and now transferring in other db by using a PHP script. The data I have in tables have HTML in original format.

Comment: No you do not store "escaped" data. You escape the data when you use it.

Comment: Or you can always store it just like that..

Comment: @salmana so how do you store `<a href = "mike'scafe.html">`

Comment: you can replace commas "," with "&comma;"

Comment: @parag I want to avoid what are you referring.

Comment: Just use PDO/mysqli AND prepared statements. They will take care of any escaping for you

Comment: You store it as any other string data. There is literally no magic around html so that it was treated differently.

Comment: You're talking about storing HTML that you buffered, and dumped to the database.  That's done with output buffering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the use of ob\_start() in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php)

Comment: @Strawberry you store it as is i.e. `<a href = "mike'scafe.html">`.

Comment: @SalmanA Care to provide a working example?

Comment: @Strawberry you probably missed the point. I am suggesting that OP stores `<a href = "mike'scafe.html">` instead of `&lt;a href = "mike\'scafe.html"&gt;`

Comment: @SalmanA Well, one of us certainly has ;-)

Comment: @Volatil3 which solution do you like more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use htmlentities($myHtml, ENT_QUOTES) when retriving the html
and
Use mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$myHtml) before inserting to database

Comment: See prepared statements

Comment: @cr1xus You need to assemble the HTML before you enter it into the database, which would be most easily done with creating a PHP output object with ob_*

Comment: @3.14159265358... `ob_start` will not work here as I am not outputting page HTML

Comment: Mysqli is meant for mysql databases only.

Answer (score 0):

in the code below you will be putting the HTML being processed:

```
        ob_start();
        //rendering html

        //end of rendering html
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    echo $html;

        $sql = $pdo_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO processed (`id`, `html`, ) VALUES (:id, :html)");
        $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $sql->bindParam(':html', $html);
        $sql->execute();
```