# Issue in loading a specific div of php page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load a div of my php page by using a code

$('#show_contractor').load('display_cont.php');

But, I can't able to load and during running that whole div table data are invisible. After refreshing the whole page only, i will get the data. Can you people help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your console for errors.

Comment: This much info is not enough to help you. Can you share 1) your relevant markup 2) response from php file

Comment: `$('#show_contractor').load('display_cont.php', 
    function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
          alert(textStatus);
        }
});` try to add this. then check if you are getting any alert.

Comment: Yeah! I added this code. But i didnt get any alert.

Comment: Try to decode this like: _I can't able to load and during running that whole div table data are invisible. After refreshing the whole page only, i will get the data._

Comment: My code is, I am adding a user. So if i click assign button, My data should entered into database and only the display table should be loaded instead of loading the whole page.   This is my div "<div id="show_contractor"><?php include 'display_cont.php';?></div>"

Comment: You should look into output buffering. An example can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php .. The content will be stored into `$output`. You generate your full HTML that you can `echo` out.

Comment: Thank you. I will work it out.