# i am stucking when i submitt my contact form

Tags: php

I have made a contact from... which is supposed to redirect a user to the "THANK YOU" page once the details of the same is submitted; However on submitting.. the user is not getting directed to the "THANK YOU PAGE". Can you please find out the mistake ? I would be really grateful.. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

```
<?php 
include("company_profile/lib/data.config.php"); 
$btnsubmit  =isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])?$_POST['btnsubmit']:'';
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$cource = $_POST['cource'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$created_date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');
$q="Insert INTO enquiry_form SET name='$name',email='$email',
contact='$phone',message='$message',cource='$cource',
created_date='$created_date',etime='$time'";

    $r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);

   if($r) 
    {
    //echo "Thankyou for Inquery";
    header("location:thanks.php");
    //echo "<script>alert('Message Send')</script>";



  }else
  {
    echo "there was a problem";
  }

  }

  ?>
```

Comment: Query syntaxe pb... and have a look on sql injection ...https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection

Comment: For one thing `$btnsubmit  =isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])?$_POST['btnsubmit']:'';
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))` you shouldn't do that, and second; where's the html form for this?

Comment: You're wide open to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't already.  Never concatenate arbitrary data directly into the query.  Use bound parameters with PDO or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You try sql below

```
      INSERT INTO enquiry_form(name,email,contact,message,courece,created_date,etime) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
if($stmt=$conn->prepare($q){
$stmt->bind_param('/dependent your datatype',$name,$email,$contact,...);
$stmt->execute();
echo "<script>
window.location.href='thank.php';
alert('Thank you');
</script>"
```

;
}

Comment: my code is working fine value succefully saved in a databse  but the page not redirect

Comment: you can try `<script>window.location.href = thank.php</script>`

Comment: wait me a minute , i edit comment and help you avoid sql injection

Comment: @arifkhan i edit it , you can try and if it helpful dont forget vote for me ^^

Comment: sir when i am using form action thanks.php then my code is redirect thanks.php but same time i am not getting submit details in my database

Answer (score 0):

Try this with checking for last inserted id then it will redirect you to your destination script. And please post your html form. Maybe is error in there too. This must work 100%.

Php code in contact-page.php

```
<?php 

include("company_profile/lib/data.config.php");

if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
    $cource = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cource']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
    $created_date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    $q = "INSERT INTO enquiry_form ( name, email, contact, message, cource, created_date, etime ) VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$message', '$cource', '$created_date', '$time' )";

    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

    // if is returned last inserted id
    if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)) 
    {
        header("location:thanks.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "there was a problem";
    }

}

?>
```

Html form in contact-page.php

```
<form  action="contact-page.php" method="POST">
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required /><br>
    <label>Subject</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="cource" required /><br>
    <label>Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" required /><br>
    <label>Phone</label><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10,11}" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required /><br>
    <label>Message</label><br>
    <textarea cols="46" rows="3" name="message" required></textarea><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Sumbit" name="btnsubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: ys mario u r right i will have to mantion action="contact-page.php" then every thing working fine thanks a lot mario and and saeed who saved my job

Answer (score 0):

*use pdo again and filter your request*

```
<?php
include("company_profile/lib/data.config.php"); 
$btnsubmit  =isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])?$_POST['btnsubmit']:'';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name']; // filter string  number encode ......
$email = $_POST['email']; // filter string number encode ......
$phone = $_POST['phone']; // filter string number encode ......
$cource = $_POST['cource']; // filter string number encode ......
$message = $_POST['message']; // filter string number encode ......
$created_date = date('Y-m-d'); // filter string number encode ......
// we are in 2017 use pdo
$pdo = $con->prepare("Insert INTO enquiry_form SET name= :name,email=:email,contact=:phone,message=:message,cource=:cource,created_date= now()");
$pdo->execute(array('name' => $name,'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone, 'message' => $message, 'cource' => $cource ));
   if($pdo) 
    {
    //echo "Thankyou for Inquery";
    header("location:thanks.php");
    //echo "<script>alert('Message Send')</script>";



  }else
  {
    echo "there was a problem";
  }

  }
}
 ?>`
```

Comment: see i would like to tell u my condition of code  i have a three file first file name is contact-us.php and second file is contact-page .php and third file name is thanks.php and i m doing include contact-page.php file in contact-us.php and i did share my contact-page.php file.and one for thing i have given action="thanks.php" in contact-page.php

Answer (score -1):

In php you need to write ob_start(); at the start of your code to get your headers to buffer. You can see this previous post on the importance of ob_start: [What's the use of ob_start() in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php) or check out the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php . 
 If you don't have that snippit of code, your header won't work.

Comment: can u edit the same code whatever u said please i stucking at my office

Comment: I did not. Try adding ob_start(); after <?php and see if it helps. I should mention that this will help your redirect issues, but not necessarily your database issues.

Comment: see when i am remove form action="thanks.php" than my previous code working fine the value of form is succesfully save in database but the page  is not redirect on thanks.php

Comment: and when i give form action="thanks.php" then page is successfully redirect on thanks.php but the form values i am not getting in my database

Comment: did you alter your insert as above to INTO enquiry_form ( name, email, contact, message, cource, created_date, etime ) VALUES ( '$name', '$email', '$phone', '$message', '$cource', '$created_date', '$time' )"; as suggested by Mario?

Comment: Another thing you could try is action =" $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] " and putting the contents of contact-page at the start with if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {... if you find the page jumping is causing errors

Comment: no i just onlu change my form action="contact-page.php" only accept this my previous code same which i post as a question