# Why is the server mysteriously sending headers after page load?

Tags: php, http-headers

The following code, for some odd reason, works without error when the condition is true. I would like to know why, contrary to [the expected error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php), it *works*.

```
include('includes/header.html');
echo "<div class = 'col-sm-6'>";
if (!ISADMIN && !(isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_GET['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id'])) {
  @require('includes/login_functions.inc.php');     
  redirect_user(''); // Redirects successfully
}
```

The function above, `redirect_user()`, is in an includes file, and I call the function at the top of the most of my PHP files. Mainly, the function calls

```
header("Location: $url")
```

where $url is a local function scope variable.

The headers have already been sent, and HTML has already been both dynamically through PHP and statically through HTML printed to the page. However, as per the conditional, the user is still redirected if the conditional returns true. The reason this is a problem is when I try to reproduce it in a new file, I get the error I expect,

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

Additionally, I get this error as expected without the conditional, just calling `redirect_user()`.

The `includes` directory is located on the repository's [GitHub](https://github.com/Borumer/Borum/blob/stack-question-58495500/pages/includes/header.html). The page on the live site is http://www.bforborum.com/test

**Edit**

I have found that output_buffering was on, and I turned it off to no avail. With this set to 0, everything redirects whether or not headers are sent.

Comment: Are you saying sometimes calling `header()` will throw the warning and sometimes it will not? You're concerned about the cases when that warning is not thrown, correct?

Comment: _>> Additionally, I get this error without the conditional, just calling redirect_user()_. 
So, when it goes into your if statement then the error is thrown? If so, that is exactly what is supposed to happen. You have already output content with the `echo` so any call to `header(...)` will throw that warning.

Comment: @waterloomatt In the first script I made, the warning is not thrown. In the second script I made when trying to reproduce this, it throws the warning.

Comment: @waterloomatt I know why it is throwing the error when it does...when it doesn't is where I am confused

Comment: I suspect it is not going into your if statement therefor not issuing the header. Your if statement logic seems to contradict itself. How can `session['id'] == get['id']` if `!session['id'] && get['id']`? Hope that's clear.

Comment: @waterloomatt No, it _is_ redirecting when the condition returns true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201235/discussion-between-marvin-and-waterloomatt).

Comment: I really don't have enough information to go on here. Can you provide something for me to reproduce it? Are you sure you're not buffering output with `ob_start`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *I did not find this answer by myself. [waterloomatt](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/296555/waterloomatt) helped me, but at the time the question was closed.*

The reason for all of this was that `output_buffering` was turned on, on the live site, while turned off on the localhost. Alternatively, `display_errors` was off, on the live site while turned on on the localhost. This caused inconsistent results.

Output buffering meant that it redirected even though the headers were already sent. I used `.htaccess` to set `output_buffering` to off for both the live site and `localhost`. Also, I used ob_start because using it this way was actually working better for me.

[What's the use of ob_start() in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php)