# Positioning of get_template_part()

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I created a shortcode to display social icons within the theme I am using (Divi).  The social icons are contained in a PHP template called "social_icons.php".

This is the function I am using:

```
  function social_icons_shortcode() {
    $social_icons = get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons' );
      echo $social_icons; 
}
add_shortcode('social-icons', 'social_icons_shortcode');
```

Here is the the social_icons.php template:

```
<div id="custom-social-icons">
    <?php if( get_field('facebook', 'option') ): ?>
        <a class="icon facebook" href="<?php echo get_field( 'facebook', 'option' ) ?>" title="Follow us on Facebook"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('twitter', 'option') ): ?>
    <a class="icon twitter" href="<?php echo get_field( 'twitter', 'option' ) ?>" title="Follow us on Twitter"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('instagram', 'option') ): ?>
    <a class="icon instagram" href="<?php echo get_field( 'instagram', 'option' ) ?>" title="Follow us on Instagram"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('youtube', 'option') ): ?>
    <a class="icon youtube" href="<?php echo get_field( 'youtube', 'option' ) ?>" title="Follow us on YouTube"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if( get_field('linkedin', 'option') ): ?>
    <a class="icon linkedin" href="<?php echo get_field( 'linkedin', 'option' ) ?>" title="Find us on Linkedin"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

The shortcode works fine when I want to show the social icons in the footer of the theme but when I try to put them into the body (eg: the contact page) they are displaying absolute at the upper left hand corner of the page. See Screenshot:  https://share.getcloudapp.com/8LuJkODx

I cannot figure out why this is happening - is there something I am doing wrong with get_template_part()?

Comment: Please post the contents of the social_icons template. Also, it could be a CSS issue.

Comment: Thank you @disinfor - I've just updated the original question with the contents of the template.

Comment: Can you provide the CSS for those? It looks like you are using absolute positioning based on how it is displayed.

Comment: Thank you @MarkTruitt - that was my first thought too as sometimes I am fighting the theme but it was not a positioning issue.  Disinfor's answer below sorted it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh..I see what the problem is. You need to `return` the value, not `echo`.

```
function social_icons_shortcode() {
    $social_icons = get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons' );
    return $social_icons; 
}
add_shortcode('social-icons', 'social_icons_shortcode');
```

The other thing that may happen because how `get_template_part()` works, you may need to use an `ob_buffer`.

```
function social_icons_shortcode() {
      ob_start();
      get_template_part( 'includes/social_icons' );
      return ob_get_clean(); 
}
add_shortcode('social-icons', 'social_icons_shortcode');
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much @disinfor - its displaying where it is shown.  I had tried to return it previously but that didn't work - I must look up ob_buffer now :-)!

Comment: Glad you got it working! Object Buffering is pretty awesome. Super useful for a large amount of HTML that a shortcode (or anything) needs to return the markup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401949/whats-the-use-of-ob-start-in-php